# Quickbooks Online "restore point"?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am considering redoing a large portion of the way I have been managing my books in Quickbooks Online.  I would like to create a "restore point" of some kind though, in cases I end up messing things up.  Is there a way to do this so if I do anything wrong, I can always go back to a specific point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Quickbooks Online does not offer this feature.  You can make a backup in the event that you want to switch to the Desktop version of the software, but that backup cannot be restored to the Online Edition.

I would suggest, at the very least, exporting some reports to your system, either to Excel or PDF, so that you have a record of what was there before you started changing things.  In the event that you want to 'undo' your changes, that would have to be done manually, but at least you'd have a record of where you'd want to get back to.

Quickbooks Online also keeps an Activity Log that tracks changes that are made to your transactions.  To access this feature:

1. Choose Company > Activity Log.
2. From any listed transaction, click the icon under the History column. This will take you to its Audit Trail page.  Data that was changed is shown in red text.

PS - Be careful not to change transactions from past years for which tax returns have already been filed.  If you need to do this, it may be wise to speak to your accountant, as it can end up giving you (and them) a big headache next tax season!

Answer (score -1):

You can restore your data with QuickBooks on the desktop version.
If you want to do backup data from a hard drive or a network folder, go for the following steps.

- Open QuickBooks and click open the File menu.
- Open or Restore Company to open the restore wizard.
- Click on- "restor a back up copy"
- This takes you to the Backup copy window.
- Opt the drop-down option and select the backup file saved location.
- Backup file saved location will always have a .qbb extension.
- Select the file and open it.

[image]